# Is there a brand of salsa I can cook with that doesn't contain seeds?

Tags: mexican-cuisine, salsa

I love salsa, mexican food, and anything spicy, but most salsa has tomato and or Jalapeno seeds in there. Hope to find one without seeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't trust any store brand to omit seeds entirely; it's just not going to be a priority for them.

I'd suggest making your own instead.  It's fairly easy and fast to seed tomatoes using a chinois, and to seed peppers using a knife.  And it'll taste better, too!

Comment: Smaller peppers like jalapenos are also easy to seed with a small spoon.